# How to find how many customer buy more than one stuff from a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Table sales:

```
  create table sales (  
    Date date,  
    customer_id integer,  
    product_id integer,  
    units_sold integer,  
    paid_amount integer  
    );

Insert into sales (Date, customer_id, product_id, units_sold, paid_amount)  
VALUES  
('2016-01-01', '1', '1', '5', '45'),  
('2016-01-01', '2', '1', '2', '18'),  
('2016-01-01', '3', '2', '7', '35'),  
('2016-01-07', '1', '3', '3', '45'),  
('2016-01-07', '2', '2', '5', '25'),  
('2016-01-07', '4', '2', '5', '25'),  
('2016-01-10', '1', '4', '5', '30'),  
('2016-01-10', '2', '4', '5', '30'),  
('2016-01-10', '4', '5', '6', '60'),  
('2016-01-10', '4', '3', '9', '135'),  
('2016-01-14', '3', '1', '4', '60'),  
('2016-01-14', '2', '3', '6', '90'),  
('2016-01-14', '2', '3', '6', '90');
```

How many    customers   bought more than    one different   product on  every   visit   (i.e.   day)?

Comment: Unrelated, but: numbers should be specified **without** single quotes in SQL. `'45'` is a string, `45`  is a number

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that's a different table which has no use here, we can get the result only with this table

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name we have a product_id in this table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name all the product_id identities for some vegetable nothing else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `group by` and get the `count()` like

```
select customer_id, count(distinct product_id) as item_purchased
from sales 
group by "date", customer_id
having count(distinct product_id) > 1;
```

Comment: Your query is returning answer 2, but when we look into the data it's 1, only one customer with customer_id = '4' has more than one different vegetable purchased on the same date.

Comment: @ashutoshsingh, per your posted data and question that's correct

Comment: When you look into the data, last two rows are same i.e, duplicate. Which means customer_id = 2 has bought same product twice in the same day. So it should not considered in the result. Since the questions is asking for more than one different product.

Comment: Hi @Rahul , If I have to find the 2nd most paid amount product in every day... I am trying  
SELECT *   
FROM (  
    SELECT   
           date,   
           customer_id,   
           product_id,  
      paid_amount,  
           rank() OVER (  
             PARTITION BY date   
             ORDER BY paid_amount   
             DESC  
            )   
    FROM sales) s   
WHERE rank = 2;  
It doesn't give the result for date 14th. Could you help

Comment: @ashutoshsingh, you can probably do a `order by` like `order by count(distinct product_id) desc limit 1,1`. Moreover, post a separate question for that.

Comment: @ashutoshsingh: `more than one different product on every visit` Customer#4 visited on 2016-01-07, but bought only one different product, which does not satisfy `on **every** visit` (maybe you should reformulate your question?)